# debugging JavaScript with IE (10)

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, visual-studio, internet-explorer

I am trying to execute VS Express 2013 for Web using Internet Explorer 10.  When I press the PF12 to see the AJAX, I put a break point and when I try to execute I got this error  Unable to attach to process. Another debugger might be attached to the process.   Anyone knows how to avoid this error?

Comment: Maybe this could help you http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/317704/JScript-Debugger-Unable-to-attach-the-process-Anot

Comment: @EduardoQuintana Options in Debug are  Continue - Stop Debugging - Build - Step Into - Step Over - Step Out - Toggle Breakpoint - Windows - Clear All Data Tips - Export Data Tips - Import Data Tips - Options and Settings - Properties   I don't see any DETACH ALL...  any more idea ?

Comment: Debug -> Windows -> Processes, right-click on the name of the process you want to detach, search for one of Javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally decided to install Google Chrome.   It works right away and I saw my error.